# Al intentar instanciar un objeto, aparece AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute <el_atributo>

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto en python usando POO para entender un poco más sobre el tema. El proyecto consiste en la gestión de cuentas de banco: hice métodos para crear una cuenta, realizar depósito, retiro, consulta de saldo, ver las cuentas existentes y eliminar una cuenta.

En el bloque principal hice un menú donde seleccionas qué es lo que quieres realizar.

Realmente ya tengo toda mi clase terminada y creo que está bien, el problema aparece cuando quiero instanciar el objeto, pero quiero hacerlo una vez ejecutado el código, o sea, desde la terminal. Lo que quiero hacer es seleccionar la opción de crear una cuenta y ahí instanciar el objeto (cuenta), pero no logro que el nombre de la variable se asigne al self, no sé si me explico.

Todos los datos son ingresados por mediante inputs y si se guarda el objeto, pero cuando quiero hacer un método de clase no reconoce el self.

A continuación les dejo el código.

```
    import random
    import csv
    lista = list("0123456789")
    
    class cuenta:
        clientes = []
        def __init__(self, saldo = 0):
            self.__nombreC = input("Nombre completo del cliente: ").title()
            self.__fechaN = input("Fecha de nacimiento del cliente: ")
            self.__lugarN = input("Lugar de nacimiento del cliente: ").upper()
            self.numeroT = int(input("Número telefónico del cliente: "))
            self.saldo = saldo
            def numero_cuenta():
                num = random.choices(lista,k=18)
                num = "".join(num)
                return num
            def numero_cliente():
                n = random.choices(lista, k=6)
                n = "".join(n)
                return n
            self.__cuenta = numero_cuenta()
            self.__cliente = numero_cliente()
            cuenta.clientes.append(self)
            
            with open ("Cuentas.csv", 'w', newline='\n') as ccsv:           
                writer = csv.writer(ccsv, delimiter=",",dialect= 'excel')
                for cuentas in cuenta.clientes:
                    writer.writerow(cuentas.__dict__.values())
                ccsv.close()
        
            
        
        @property
        def nombre(self):
            return self.__nombreC
        
        @property
        def fechan(self):
            return self.__fechaN
        
        @property
        def lugarn(self):
            return self.__lugarN
        
        
        @property
        def cuenta(self):
            return self.__cuenta
        
        @property
        def cliente(self):
            return self.__cliente
        
        
        def deposito(self, cantidad):
            self.saldo = self.saldo + cantidad
        
        @staticmethod
        def retiro(self):
            claveint = input("Ingrese la clave interbancaria del cliente: ")
            if claveint == self.__cuenta:
                cantidad = int(input("Que cantidad desea retirar?: "))
                if cantidad > self.saldo:
                    return "No dispone suficiente efectivo"
                else:
                    self.saldo = self.saldo - cantidad
            else:
                return "Esa clave no es correcta"
        
        def consulta(self):
            return f"Su saldo actual es de ${self.saldo}"
        
        @classmethod        
        def cuentas_existentes(cls):
            with open("Cuentas.csv", 'r' ,newline='\n') as ccsv:
                reader1 = csv.reader(ccsv, dialect= 'excel',delimiter = ',')
                for contacto in reader1:
                    print (contacto)
            ccsv.close()
        
            
        
        def eliminar_cuenta(self):
            if self.saldo == 0:
                cuenta.clientes.remove(self)
                del self
                with open ("Cuentas.csv", 'w', newline='\n') as ccsv:           
                    writer = csv.writer(ccsv, delimiter=",",dialect= 'excel')
                    for cuentas in cuenta.clientes:
                        writer.writerow(cuentas.__dict__.values())
                    ccsv.close()
                print ("La cuenta se ha cerrado")
            else:
                return "Tiene que retirar todo su efectivo"
        
        def __del__(self):
            return "se ha borrado la cuenta"
                    
        def __repr__(self) -> str:
            return f"{self.__class__.__name__} ('{self.__nombreC}', '{self.__fechaN}', '{self.__lugarN}','{self.numeroT}', '${self.saldo}' ,'{self.__cuenta}', '{self.__cliente}')"
        
        
    
    print ("Banco DGF")
    while True:
        print ("Seleccione la opción deseada: ")
        opcion = int(input("""
               1.- Crear nueva cuenta
               2.- Mostrar cuentas existentes
               3.- Realizar deposito a una cuenta
               4.- Realizar retiro de una cuenta
               5.- Consultar estado de cuenta
               6.- Eliminar cuenta
               
               """))
        if opcion == 1:
            usuario = str(input("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: "))
            usuario = cuenta()
        elif opcion == 2:
            print (cuenta.clientes)
        elif opcion == 3:
             usuario = str(input("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: "))
             cantidad = int(input("Introduzca la cantidad a depositar"))
             cuenta.deposito(usuario, cantidad)
        elif opcion == 4:
            usuario = str(input("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: "))
            cuenta.retiro(usuario)
        elif opcion == 5:
            usuario = str(input("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: "))
            cuenta.consulta(usuario)
        elif opcion == 6:
            usuario = str(input("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: "))
            cuenta.eliminar_cuenta(usuario)
        else:
            print ("Seleccione una opcion valida, p.ej: 1 o 2")
```

y el error que me sale cuando por ejemplo quiero hacer un depósito es este:

> Introduzca el nombre del cliente: Damian
> Introduzca la cantidad a depositar3000
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\intel.spyder-py3\Proyectos\Gestion_de_cuentas_de_banco\Proyecto.py", line 137, in 
> cuenta.deposito(usuario, cantidad)
> File "C:\Users\intel.spyder-py3\Proyectos\Gestion_de_cuentas_de_banco\Proyecto.py", line 68, in deposito
> self.saldo = self.saldo + cantidad
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'saldo'

Answer (score 1):

El error está en la última línea

```
elif opcion == 3:
    usuario = str(input("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: "))
    cantidad = int(input("Introduzca la cantidad a depositar"))
    cuenta.deposito(usuario, cantidad)
```

Estás llamando a `deposito` con dos parámetros (`usuario` y `cantidad`, pero el método está definido con uno solo:

```
def deposito(self, cantidad):
    self.saldo = self.saldo + cantidad
```

La forma correcta sería

```
cuenta.deposito(cantidad)
```

Pero repites el mismo error en múltiples partes.

Veras: `cuenta` es un objeto que ya tiene el cliente y sus datos guardados. No necesitas pasar el cliente al ejecutar un método del objeto.

Cuando declaradas un método, el primer parámetro es siempre `self`, pero cuando llamas al método, debe hacer cuenta que ese parámetro no existe.

Por ejemplo:

```
def consulta(self):
    return f"Su saldo actual es de ${self.saldo}"
```

debe ser llamado con:

```
cuenta.consulta()
```

**no** con

```
cuenta.consulta(usuario)
```

Comment: Gracias por la observación, sin embargo ese no era mi problema, creo que realmente no lo supe explicar pero hace unos momentos logré resolverlo, lo que yo quería era instanciar objetos desde la la consola y poder acceder los metodos, p ej. crear 5 cuentas diferentes y poder hacer todo con cada una de ellas, pero no 1 x 1 si no en el momento que quisiera, lo logré usando defautldict y poniendo un input en la llave del diccionario:  """

Comment: Usuarios = defaultdict()                                                                                             
       if opcion == 1:
          Usuarios[input("Cliente: ")] = cuenta()                                                            
        elif opcion == 3:
         cantidad = int(input("Introduzca la cantidad a depositar: "))
         print (Usuarios[input("Cliente: ")].deposito(cantidad))                                                    Espero que se entienda, gracias.